# Use hibernate when saving objects to the database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

In my java application I have some serialized entity classes with inheritance. When saving instances of these classes i am converting them to a byte array and saving to a longblob column in my database table. Is there any advantage using hibernate to implement this program. Because as far I understand hibernate is used to map entities with database tables in a proper way. But here I don't have a relational model to map attributes of entities. I am saving them as objects. Am I missing something. Please clarify me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you're missing something, but with your design, you won't be able to express *queries* over your data, or to access the data stored using a language other than Java, or even to easily update the code of your entities and still be able to read the data stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a relational data model to save those objects and you can't change your schema, then you can use your current approach.

If you use PostgreSQL you might be interested in [JSON storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) as well. That way you can store your hierarchies using JSON objects and you can even run native SQL queries against them (although not inheritance-aware, but you can cope with that if you use some _class column to differ between object types).

The cleanest approach is to have the relation model in sync with your business domain model. That way you can benefit from:

- optimistic locking ([preventing lost updates phenomena](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/))
- caching (2nd level cache and query cache)
- query-able hierarchies
- an external DBA hierarchies could run an update on your hierarchies using mere SQL
- [auditing](http://envers.jboss.org/)